# How do I use a templated class within a new template?

Tags: c++, templates

Not sure why, but the code in xcode just started working.  I am very happy.
Thank you all for your time.

```
//here is JUCE's code
//==============================================================================
/** This template-overloaded class can be used to convert between var and custom types.


    @tags{Core}
*/
    template <class Type> struct VariantConverter
    {
        static Type fromVar (const var& v)              { return static_cast<Type> (v); }
        static var toVar (const Type& t)                { return t; }
    };
//here is my addition
    template <> struct VariantConverter<Point<int>>
    {
        static Point<int> fromVar (const var& v)
        {
            return Point<int>
            (
             { v[0].operator int(), v[1].operator int() }
             );
        }
        static var toVar (const Point<int>& p)
        {
            return Array<var>({ p.getX(), p.getY() });
        }
    };
```

Hi, I am not sure how I can achieve the above code.  A class like typedef to replace the

```
Point<int>
```

would be great.  I am appending a JUCE file.

Xcode gives me two errors

```
/Tools/JUCE/modules/juce_core/containers/juce_Variant.h:41:18: Expected unqualified-id
```

and

```
/Tools/JUCE/modules/juce_core/containers/juce_Variant.h:343:46: Expected '>'
```

Thank you

Comment: What you are showing seems like it is a template specialization. Are you sure, that you don't have a general template of `VariantConverter` somewhere in your codebase?

Comment: You didn't ever define `var` either. Was it the template type of the non-specialised version?

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and especially how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

As there are only static methods you don't need an Object of that type. You should be able to call it like:

```
typedef Point<int> MyPoint;

MyPoint point(1,2); // call constructor of a Point<int>
var x = VariantConverter::toVar(point); //call static methods of struct
MyPoint point2 = VariantConverter::fromVar(x);
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the info to the question along with a copy of the two errors.

Comment: I cannot tell anything about the two errors with the given information. You should at least post the  code where the errors are listed.

Answer (score 0):

```
template <>
struct VariantConverter<Point<int>>
{ /* ... */ };
```

What you have here is a template *specialisation*. If you want to specialise, you first need a base template before you can compile.

```
template <typename>
struct VariantConverter;
```

Sometimes it is useful if *only* the specialisations exist, then you would just declare the base as above, fare mor common, though, is having a default implementation:

```
template <typename T>
struct VariantConverter
{
    static T fromVar(var const& v);
};
```

Solely, what shall `var` be in above example? T as well? Another template parameter of `VariantConverter` struct? Third option is the one I show: function template parameter:

```
template <typename T>
struct VariantConverter
{
    template <typename var>
    static T fromVar(var const& v);
};
```

You now can provide a default implementation suitable for the majority of types – if there *is* a reasonable one (otherwise, it might be more appropriate not to implement the default and just have the specialisations).

OK, *now* we can specialise:

```
template <>
struct VariantConverter<Point<int>>
// Point<int> now is what previously was T; could be any arbitrary type, not
// necessarily Point<int>, but std::string, double, ...
{
    // still, you need to tell what var actually is
    // maybe you have defined a class for already? similar to std::vector?
    // assuming so this time...
    static Point<int> fromVar (var const& v)
    {
        return Point<int>
        (
           // are you sure point accepts an initializer list?
           // or do you intend to create first a point and then
           //  use move/copy constructor???
           //{ v[0].operator int(), v[1].operator int() }
           // rather normal constructor directly:
           //v[0].operator int(), v[1].operator int()
           // however, explicitly calling cast operators is ugly, rather just cast:
           static_cast<int>(v[0]), static_cast<int>(<v[1])
           // or C style casts, if you prefer
           //(int)v[0], (int)v[1]
           // I personally would rather go with the former, though, for being
           // more "C++-ish"
        );
    }
};
```

Now maybe you are looking for something totally different:

```
template <typename T>
struct VariantConverter
{
    static Point<T> fromVar(std::vector<T> const& v)
    {
        return Point<T>(v[0], v[1]);
    }
};
```

Finally, as you explicitly asked for:

```
template <>
struct VariantConverter<Point<int>>
{
    using Type = Point<int>;
    static Type fromVar(/* ... */);
};
```

or, for second variant:

```
template <typename T>
struct VariantConverter
{
    using Type = Point<T>;
    static Type fromVar( /* ... */);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my poor communication.  English is my first language and despite being educated, I am not gifted at written communication.  Here is the bigger context.  I am trying to add to an existing class.

```
//This is the end of their code
  //==============================================================================
/** This template-overloaded class can be used to convert between var and custom types.


    @tags{Core}
*/
    template <class Type> struct VariantConverter
    {
        static Type fromVar (const var& v)              { return static_cast<Type> (v); }
        static var toVar (const Type& t)                { return t; }
    };
//here is my code
    template <> struct VariantConverter<Point<int>>
    {
        static Point<int> fromVar (const var& v)
        {
            return Point<int>
            (
             { v[0].operator int(), v[1].operator int() }
             );
        }
        static var toVar (const Point<int>& p)
        {
            return Array<var>({ p.getX(), p.getY() });
        }
    };
```

Comment: This should be edited into the question and not added as an answer. So what is the problem here? Not compiling? Show the error message. Not working? Show what it does and what you expected.